# How to fix html css styling issue?

Tags: html, css

I want to get the text box in the center but slightly to the left, and the picture overlapping the text box on the right hand side of the text box (left of the picture).

https://ibb.co/XDHNKPd - link to what it looks like

```css
#parent2 {
  position: relative;
  width: 700px;
  height: 500px;
}

.aboutme {
  background-color: white;
  padding: 80px;
  border-radius: 25px;
  width: 640px;
  height: 230px;
  font-size: 18px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  text-align: left;
  position: absolute;
}

.aboutme h1 {
  color: #000;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
  -webkit-text-stroke-width: 0.5px;
}

.aboutme h1:hover {
  -webkit-text-fill-color: black;
}

.aboutme p {
  margin-top: 35px;
}

.pictureofme {
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<div id="parent2">
  <div class="aboutme">
    <h1>About Me</h1>
    <p>Student at the University of Lincoln studying Computer Science (first year). A hard-working, responsible and enthusiastic learner. I'm keen to find a part-time job/summer internship or a volunteering experience. Always motivated with a willingness
      to learn new attributes and obtain new business experience.
    </p>
  </div>
  <div class="pictureofme">
    <img src="images/fb.png" alt="Avatar" width="300" height="300">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You want the text aligned toward left and the image on the right hand side?

Comment: @ZamAbdulVahid  something like this https://ibb.co/YQLqqVG

Comment: Please check the updated below code snippet

Comment: @ZamAbdulVahid thanks alot

Comment: Appreciate if you could mark the answer as accepted as it would help other community members identify answers quickly who are looking for similar solutions.

Answer (score 0):

Slight tweak to your code.

You can adjust the image width as per your preference.

```css
#parent2 {
  display: flex;
  padding: 30px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.aboutme {
  font-size: 18px;
  padding: 25px 50px 25px 25px;
  background: #f5f7f8;
  border-radius: 10px;
}

.aboutme h1 {
  color: #000;
  margin:0 0 30px 0;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
  -webkit-text-stroke-width: 0.5px;
}
.aboutme h1:hover {
  -webkit-text-fill-color: black;
}

.pictureofme img{
  width: 200px;
  margin-left:-20px;
}
```

```html
<div id="parent2">
  <div class="aboutme">
    <h1>About Me</h1>
    <p>Student at the University of Lincoln studying Computer Science (first year). A hard-working, responsible and enthusiastic learner. I'm keen to find a part-time job/summer internship or a volunteering experience. Always motivated with a willingness
      to learn new attributes and obtain new business experience.
    </p>
  </div>
  <div class="pictureofme">
    <img src="https://www.spicefactors.com/wp-content/uploads/default-user-image.png" alt="Avatar"/>
  </div>
</div>
```